# Pandas Month-To-Date rolling sum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

We can apply a 30D monthly rolling sum operations as:

```
df.rolling("30D").sum()
```

However, how can I achieve a month-to-date (or even year-to-date) rolling sum in a similar fashion?
Month-to-date meaning that we only sum from the beginning of the month up to the current date (or row)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following database:

```
    Year  Month  week  Revenue
0   2020      1     1       10
1   2020      1     2       20
2   2020      1     3       10
3   2020      1     4       20
4   2020      2     1       10
5   2020      2     2       20
6   2020      2     3       10
7   2020      2     4       20
8   2020      3     1       10
9   2020      3     2       20
10  2020      3     3       10
11  2020      3     4       20
12  2021      1     1       10
13  2021      1     2       20
14  2021      1     3       10
15  2021      1     4       20
16  2021      2     1       10
17  2021      2     2       20
18  2021      2     3       10
19  2021      2     4       20
20  2021      3     1       10
21  2021      3     2       20
22  2021      3     3       10
23  2021      3     4       20
```

You could use a combination of `group_by` + `cumsum` to get what you want:

```
df['Year_To_date'] = df.groupby('Year')['Revenue'].cumsum()
df['Month_To_date'] = df.groupby(['Year', 'Month'])['Revenue'].cumsum()
```

Results:

```
    Year  Month  week  Revenue  Year_To_date  Month_To_date
0   2020      1     1       10            10             10
1   2020      1     2       20            30             30
2   2020      1     3       10            40             40
3   2020      1     4       20            60             60
4   2020      2     1       10            70             10
5   2020      2     2       20            90             30
6   2020      2     3       10           100             40
7   2020      2     4       20           120             60
8   2020      3     1       10           130             10
9   2020      3     2       20           150             30
10  2020      3     3       10           160             40
11  2020      3     4       20           180             60
12  2021      1     1       10            10             10
13  2021      1     2       20            30             30
14  2021      1     3       10            40             40
15  2021      1     4       20            60             60
16  2021      2     1       10            70             10
17  2021      2     2       20            90             30
18  2021      2     3       10           100             40
19  2021      2     4       20           120             60
20  2021      3     1       10           130             10
21  2021      3     2       20           150             30
22  2021      3     3       10           160             40
23  2021      3     4       20           180             60
```

Note that **Month-to-date** makes sense only if you have a week/date column in your data model.

**EXTRAS:**
The goal of `cumsum` is to compute the cumulative sum over date by different periods. However, if the index of the original data frame is not ordered in the desired sequence,`cumsum` is computed by the original index within a group.That's because Pandas operates sequence by row indexes.

Thus, **data frame first needs to be sorted by the desired order**([Year,Month,Week] or [Date]), followed by resetting the index to match the order of the variable of interest. Now, the output is summed up by group of periods , in the chronological order.

```
df=df.sort_values(['Year', 'Month','Week']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: How safe is this in terms of the index? Assumes its ordered?

Comment: I edited my post to answer your question.